# Why is the method response of an API gateway different when being created using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I have the following terraform script which creates an API gateway that passes requests to a lambda function.

```
provider "aws" {

  access_key = "${var.access_key}"

  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  # 
  region     = "${var.region}"

  version = "~> 2.6"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "MyDemoAPI" {
  name        = "MyDemoAPI"
  description = "This is my API for demonstration purposes"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "MyDemoResource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "mydemoresource"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "MyDemoIntegration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type        = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri         = "arn:aws:apigateway:ap-southeast-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${aws_lambda_function.test_lambda_function.arn}/invocations"
  content_handling = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "200" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method}"
  status_code = "200"
  response_models {
     "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda_function" {
  filename         = "lambda.zip"
  description      = "test build api gateway and lambda function using terraform"
  function_name    = "test_lambda_function"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/my_labmda_role"
  handler          = "gateway.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python3.6"
  memory_size      = 128
  timeout          = 60
}
```

The `Method Response` section of the API gateway resource display `Select an integration response.`.

[image]

But if I create the same API gateway using AWS console, the  `Method Response` section displays something different:

[image]

Why does this happen?

The following steps are how I use AWS console to create the API gateway:

1. Select `Create Method` under the resource.
   [image]
2. Select `POST` method.
   [image]
3. Select the desired options.
   [image]

I've tried creating the above resources manually first, then execute `terraform apply`. Then terraform tells me that nothing needs to be changed.

```
terraform apply
aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI: Refreshing state... (ID: 1qa34vs1k7)
aws_lambda_function.test_lambda_function: Refreshing state... (ID: test_lambda_function)
aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource: Refreshing state... (ID: 4xej81)
aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod: Refreshing state... (ID: agm-1qa34vs1k7-4xej81-POST)
aws_api_gateway_method_response.200: Refreshing state... (ID: agmr-1qa34vs1k7-4xej81-POST-200)
aws_api_gateway_integration.MyDemoIntegration: Refreshing state... (ID: agi-1qa34vs1k7-4xej81-POST)

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

This seems to mean that the manually built structure is the same as the structure built by terraform.

Comment: The documentation on terraform.io doesn't explain this well at all. I was having literally the exact same issue and could not for the life of me figure out the difference in behavior between using terraform and the AWS console. Frequently there are "hidden" things that the console does that aren't readily apparent when working with the underlying object model directly (with terraform or otherwise). There's still a "documentation" issue open in "merged" status on GitHub about this (10772). Glad I found this stack overflow question!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because API Gateway is a complex AWS component and you can control pretty much everything on it (basically every single part of it is managed independently, giving you a lot of control over what you create but also making things harder to deal with).

See that it says "Select an Integration Response", but since your Terraform code didn't create one, it is therefore empty.

I had come across this very same problem a few weeks ago and I found the solution on Terraform's [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10157#issuecomment-263560025). I think Terraform should better document this as you're not the first one nor will you be the last to come up with this question. Well, at least we have this documented in StackOverflow now :)

Long story short, you need to add a `aws_api_gateway_integration_response` terraform resource to your API Gateway.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "MyDemoIntegrationResponse" {
   rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id}"
   resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
   http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method}"
   status_code = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.200.status_code}"

   response_templates = {
       "application/json" = ""
   } 
}
```

If you can, however, I suggest you use a proper framework to hook events to your Lambda functions (like the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) or [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/)) as it's very verbose and error prone to create them in Terraform.

Usually, I combine Terraform and Serverless Framework together: I use Terraform to create infrastructure resources - even if they are serverless - like DynamoDB tables, SQS queues, SNS topics, etc. and the Serverless Framework to create the Lambda functions and their corresponding events.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. What [Thales](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10950867/thales-minussi) suggested didn't work for me (using terraform 0.11.14 with AWS plugin 2.52.0).

Instead, I used [api_gateway_method_response](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_method_response.html) resource and set the [response_models](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_method_response.html#response_models) parameter as:

```
response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
}
```

Then it showed me the default response that all other APIs that I created through the console show!

[image]

Not very clear in terraform docs what this should look like, had to figure out myself after many attempts.

Comment: What is the difference between what you did and he has tried before?
What value did you use as status_code?

Comment: `"application/json" = ""` did not work for me (AFAIR, it's been some time since I tried that). `"application/json" = "Empty"` worked. So the difference is the value - `""` vs `"Empty"`. As for status code, I have used `status_code = "200"`.